# Sending unchecked multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm adding multiple checkboxes to a form in Wordpress that lets you check and uncheck certain features that a user should have, saved as a meta field value on the particular user in question that you're editing when submitting the form. I have set up a "user edit page" for this, so that you can make these edits directly on the front end.

The problem, that I understand is quite common but that I still couldn't find answers for in my specific case, is that unchecked boxes doesn't get sent by the form.

Let's say for example that the there would be multiple checkboxes with the same name like this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="meta[entity_access][]" value="entity1" />Entity 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="meta[entity_access][]" value="entity2" />Entity 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="meta[entity_access][]" value="entity2" />Entity 3</label>
```

If I were to check any of these boxes and submit the form, that checkbox would then already be checked when I edit the user another time. But if I then uncheck the same checkbox and send the form, returning to the user edit page it would still be checked, since the form isn't sending unchecked boxes.

I have seen solutions where you would have a hidden field for each of the checkboxes, with `0` as the value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="meta[entity_access][]" value="0" />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="meta[entity_access][]" value="entity1" />Entity 1</label>
```

But wouldn't that leave a lot of zeroes in the array of the `meta[entity_access][]`?

In the end, I would like the `meta[entity_access][]` array to contain the checkbox values that have been checked. And if a value gets unchecked, it should remove that value from the array. So using the example above, if all checkboxes apart from `entity1` were unchecked, it would return an array only containing `entity1`. If I then uncheck `entity1` and submit again, the field should return an empty array.

Comment: you have to explicitly set the index, meta[entity_access][1]

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense. But would I still need to use a hidden field or is it enough to just add the index in the name of the checkboxes?

Comment: yes of course you do

Comment: Using the hidden fields you mean? But that wouldn't let me save the value ("entity1", "entity2" for example) in the array then, I guess? Just wether that index has a 0 or a 1?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand how to do it. I would use "entity1" as the key in the array, so I would use `meta[entity_access][entity1]` as the name and then have one hidden field with the value of `0` and the actual checkbox with the value of `1` for each of the options?